# Laravel NotFoundHttpException for public directory

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-5, web-hosting

I have set up a laravel 5.4 project on a shared host which uses direct admin. I moved `public folder data` (all css, js, ...) to root of my site directory and edit `index.php` file.

Now all functionalities of my site is working but the problem is about css files. I got 404 error for all of local css files and when I checked this files in browser, laravel error has occurred. the error is

```
 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179
```

I checked that css files are uploaded and I expected that they must be accessible alone.

**Edits:**

- I'm setting up laravel in a directory not in host root, directory name is `iranttr`
- Now I uploaded again my site and this time don't move public directory contents, but problem not solved.
- I used asset() function for css, like asset('adminlte_rtl/css/AdminLTE-rtl.min.css')
- Laravel generates http://mahmoodkohansal.ir/iranttr/public/adminlte_rtl/css/AdminLTE-rtl.min.css correctly, but opening this url in browser makes NotFoundHttpException.

**Solution:**

I uploaded all files of site with FTP and the problem solved! my previous method for moving files to host was compression in local and extraction in host.

Comment: Why did you move all the public folder contents to root?

Comment: I want to remove `public` keyword from all urls. the problem does not solved without this work.

Comment: which path are you providing for css files?

Comment: The content from public, needs to be in public (Such as the css, js and the index.php). That's how Laravel's functions. What I think you're looking for is to modify the document root within httpd.conf. Your document root should be set to your public folder within Laravel, that way it effectively removes the 'public' from your URL's

Comment: did you use asset() for accessing external css files?

Comment: No need to move public folder to the root. After uploading laravel project before the root folder, rename the public folder of laravel project to public_html (root folder name of shared hosting)

Comment: thank you all, I edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: "I want to remove public keyword from all urls." you don't do that by moving the public directory, that's done by a **rule** in your `.htaccess`, if the URL rewrite is not working, check with your host company.

Comment: @teeyo Now I uploaded again my site and this time don't move public directory contents, but problem not solved.

Comment: did you put style files in the public folder?